# Not able to deploy artifacts to Nexus repository from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus, continuous-deployment

I am trying to push my artifacts to Nexus from Jenkins. I am getting the following error while I deploy to Nexus from Jenkins:

**Error message in Jenkins Console Output:**

15:59:06 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project sbx-java-webapp: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException

15:59:06 [ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon

15:59:06 [ERROR]   roleHint: "http

15:59:06 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

15:59:06 [ERROR]

15:59:06 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

15:59:06 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

15:59:06 [ERROR]

15:59:06 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

15:59:06 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I have tried several methods to make this work. But when I use maven deploy goal in my windows machine, it is deploying my artifacts to the same Nexus Repository without any failure. However from Jenkins, I am getting this error. In both environment the pom.xml and settings.xml that I use are same. I have tried with different maven versions as well in jenkins to solve this issue, but no help.

I have already tried mentioning wagonProvider in CLI as well as settings.xml and also I tried using extensions for wagonProviders in build and I even used extensions.xml and include this in descriptor in maven version 3.0.5 where WagonTransporterFactory is available, but none of them help me out. I also tried reinstalling and reconfiguring Jenkins, but that also doesn't help me.

If we can solve this issue, it will be great help. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post your console output as screenshots.  Use cut-and-paste and put the text into the Question.  (Hint: fixing that will make it more likely that someone will try to help you.)

Comment: ok Stephen, henceforth I will not share screenshots of the console output. Thanks for sharing the information. 
I mean if anyone has faced this issue before please let me know here what is the problem behind this.

Comment: I don't think you understood my hint.  Let me spell it out more clearly.  If you fix the problem **for this question**, you will increase the chance of someone answering **this question**.   A significant percentage of people who *could* answer this question either won't look at the image, or won't answer on principle ... because you are not conforming to the norms.   But hey, it is your choice.

Comment: First if you have default http transfer you don't even need to use extensions.xml (I'm ask myself what you have configured there?) Apart from that have you can you deploy from your local machine via `mvn clean deploy`?

Comment: Yes khmarbaise I was able to deploy my artifacts from my local machine where maven is already installed to nexus using the following command:

mvn clean deploy -s settings.xml

This is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh....I got the issue resolved. Another example that teaches me a small error can result in bigger issue.

The issue occurred as I was passing my Nexus Repository URL as system variable in jenkins for maven deploy command as follows:

**nexus_rel_repo="${NEXUS_REPO_URL}"**

where **NEXUS_REPO_URL** was already a String Parameter that I assigned in Jenkins. And **nexus_rel_repo** is my system variable and you can see here that I was using **double quotes** when I was assigning my Nexus Repository URL which is already a String Parameter to nexus_rel_repo. The occurrence of these extra **double quotes** disturbed the connection.

Thanks for everyone who has looked into this issue and who has already done some research on it.